# How do I create a function that pulls rasters from a list of files in a folder, runs zonal stats on them

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, gis

I am trying to create a function that loops through all of the raster grid files (watershed basins) in a folder on my computer, converts the raster (basins) to a different projection, and computes zonal statistics on the raster (basin) it pulls from an existing raster brick (precip grids from 1895-2014) stored in my .RData file. For each of the rasters (basins), a list of the zonal values needs to be returned. I have several of the zonal stats done (basins 1 through of 43), but if I could get this looping function to work, I could leave it running on my computer until it completes all of the rest of the raster basins. Here is the function I came up with;

```
>file.path="D:/Basins/basin"

>function(file.path) 
     for(i in 44:78) {
         path <- paste(file.path, i, sep="")
         basin <- raster(path)
         basin <- projectRaster(basin, precip_brick)
         precip[,i] <- zonal(precip_brick, basin, fun='mean')
         return(precip[,i])
     }
```

And then I get this;

```
Error in precip[, i] <- zonal(precip_brick, basin, fun = "mean") : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

I would try to attach some of the data, but all of the data are rasters that are rather large.

Thanks.

Comment: What's `precip`? Presumably it's not the right shape for whatever you're trying to store into it. Also, from the looks of it, you don't need `function` at all here...just the loop.

Comment: precip is supposed to be the list of values created from all of the precipitation grids in precip_brick. precip[,i] specifically was my attempt to create a list of values of mean precipitation named by precip and basin number from the list of basins in the folder. I guess I could not create a function for it, I just thought that would make it easier to reproduce in the future.

Comment: Well, do you mean a `list` or list in some other sense? If it's a `list` then you want to assign into with `precip[[i]]<-`. If you choose not to make a function, you don't need `return(precip)` at all; if you do make it a function, you want `return(precip)` outside your `for () {...}` closure otherwise the function will just return the first iteration of the loop without executing the rest of the iterations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I am hoping to get a set of values for each basin in the form of a list like you would get from the as.list() command.

Comment: I'm still just getting the last set of values from the last basin run as a matrix when running the for-loop as a function or not as a function.

Comment: Can you update your question with the most current version of the code you're using?